# i need to replace source '/root with source '/root/app in a script via sed

Tags: sed

I have written few scripts which use `source` a lot. Now I need to execute them in a different folder, which means I need to replace

```
source '/root/
```

with

```
source '/root/app
```

I have tried `sed -r` and other options but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed "s|source '/root/|source '/root/app|g"`

- `s` => Replace command.
- `|` => Delimiter used with the replace command; the string between the first and seconds | is replaced with the string between the second and third |.
  Usually / is used for the delimiter, but because you have that in your strings, something else must be used.
- `g` => The g at the end is a modifier to the s command, which would usually only replace the first occurrence of the target string in each line; with g every occurrence in the line is changed.